# Magento Unknown column core_translate.string

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error

In my `Magento` website i got an error about `core_translate` table in database and display like below :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:274:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'core_translate.string' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `core_translate`.`string`, `core_translate`.`translate` FROM `core_translate` WHERE (store_id IN (0 , :store_id)) AND (locale = :locale) ORDER BY `store_id` ASC";i:1;s:2863:"#0 example.com/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 example.com/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_tr...', Array)
#4 example.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_tr...', Array)
#5 example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(811): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Translate.php(79): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchPairs(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php(289): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Translate->getTranslationArray(NULL, 'en_US')
#8 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php(142): Mage_Core_Model_Translate->_loadDbTranslation(false)
#9 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(146): Mage_Core_Model_Translate->init('adminhtml')
#10 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(121): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->_initTranslate()
#11 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->_loadPart('translate')
#12 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(789): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->load()
#13 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(512): Mage_Core_Model_App->loadArea('adminhtml')
#14 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#15 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#16 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#17 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 example.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 example.com/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}";s:3:"url";s:21:"/demo/index.php/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/demo/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

any suggestions about that error ?.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your database table `core_translate` does not contain a column called: `string`.

What you can do is add this column manually into this table to fix the error.